# Function to find a node crashes

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a very serious problem. I have a binary tree and I want to move through the tree while I find an exact node. I have this code:

```
template<class T>
void Tree<T>::CheckTwoTimes(Node<T> *node, Node<T> *original)
{
    if(node == original) cout << "This is it" << endl;
    CheckTwoTimes(node->Left, original); //It gives error here
    CheckTwoTimes(node->Right, original);//And maybe it will give it here
}
```

`original` is the node that I'm searching for. But when I run the program it just crashes and shows me on which line is the problem. I don't know what's wrong. Maybe I don't pass the pointer parameter like it should be.

I call the function this way:

```
CheckTwoTimes(root, find); //**find** is for example the most left node
```

Comment: You probably need to do some null checks in case the children are null. Dereferencing null will cause an error. Which reminds me. What error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. I didn't get an ordinary compile error. I use Visual Studio 2010 and when I run the program it crashes and a little yellow arrow appears in the code before the line.

Answer (score 1):

At some point you're going to get to a leaf node - when this happens `node` is going to be `NULL` and you're going to try to dereference it (which is not good).

You should add a check for `NULL`:

```
template<class T>
void Tree<T>::CheckTwoTimes(Node<T> *node, Node<T> *original)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    if (node == original)
        cout << "This is it" << endl;
    CheckTwoTimes(node->Left, original);
    CheckTwoTimes(node->Right, original);
}
```

If the nodes in the tree are unique, it might also be a good idea to return a pointer to the node rather than printing something out.